# Найти матрицу-множитель в произведении матриц при известном результате

Tags: python, математика, numpy, матрицы, деление

Имеется произведение матриц `a*b=c`. Причем произведение матриц - это результат [numpy.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), а не поэлементное произведение. Известны матрицы `a` и `c`. Требуется найти матрицу `b`. Каким образом это можно сделать в python, не прибегая к решению системы уравнений с множеством неизвестных? Если просто делить `numpy.matrix`, то получается совсем не тот результат.

Вот пример:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[ 1.,  2.],[ 3.,  4.]])
c = np.matrix([[ 2.],[ 1.]])
c/a
Out[201]: 
matrix([[ 2.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.33333333,  0.25      ]])
```

Решил письменно обратную задачу, получил ответ:

```
([[-3. ],
  [ 2.5]])
```

Проверяем:

```
b= np.matrix([[-3. ],[ 2.5]])
a*b
Out[207]: 
matrix([[ 2.],
        [ 1.]])
```

Если переводить в `ndarray`, то то же самое получается:

```
c.getA()/a.getA()
Out[213]: 
array([[ 2.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.25      ]])
```

Comment: у меня получается тот результат. Вы можете привести воспроизводимый пример матриц?

Comment: Лучше добавить пример матриц в вопрос - нажмите [кнопку править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/741574/edit)

Comment: @MaxU добавил пример. Может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: а вам обязательно `matrix` использовать? Чем не подходит 2D array?

Comment: @MaxU ndarray то же самое выдаёт

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [обратной (inverse) матрицей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0):

```
In [224]: b = np.linalg.inv(a) * c

In [225]: b
Out[225]:
matrix([[-3. ],
        [ 2.5]])
```

Это будет работать для объектов типа `numpy.matrix`.
Если `a` и `c` - объекты типа `numpy.ndarray`, то нужно использовать `dot product` (как в [ответе @MarianD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741657/211923)):

```
In [8]: np.linalg.inv(a).dot(c)
Out[8]:
matrix([[-3. ],
        [ 2.5]])
```

PS использование `dot product` (операции умножения матриц как это понимается в линейной алгебре) - является более универсальным решением, т.к. оно правильно работает как для объектов типа `numpy.matrix` так и для `numpy.ndarray`:

```
In [10]: np.linalg.inv(a.getA()).dot(c.getA())
Out[10]:
array([[-3. ],
       [ 2.5]])
```

---

Пояснение:

A * B = C  | умножим обе части на A<sup>-1</sup>

умножение матриц операция некомутативная, т.е.  `A * B != B * A`, поэтому чтобы получилась единичная матрица будем делать так:

A<sup>-1</sup> * A * B = A<sup>-1</sup> * C

=>

B = A<sup>-1</sup> * C

**UPDATE:** [во многих случаях гораздо выгоднее решить систему уравнений, по сравнению с нахождением обратной матрицы](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/) (спасибо [@jfs за подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741574/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5/741601?noredirect=1#comment1134954_741601)):

```
In [328]: b = np.linalg.solve(a, c)

In [329]: b
Out[329]:
matrix([[-3. ],
        [ 2.5]])
```

Вот некоторые из преимуществ подхода решения системы линейных уравнений по сравнению с нахождением обратной матрицы:

- решение СЛУ (системы линейных уравнений) дает более точные численные результаты по сравнению с методами, использующими перемножение матриц. [Пример скалярного произведения возвращающего неточный результат](https://youtu.be/N05yYbUZMSQ?t=12m20s)
- при использовании разреженных матриц (sparse matrices) есть [методы](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve), позволяющие найти решение и возвращающие также разреженные матрицы (если это возможно), что существенно экономит использование памяти. Обратная же матрица в общем случае не будет разреженной и может занимать на несколько порядков больше памяти. Например разреженная матрица размерности 1.000.000 x 1.000.000 у которой всего 1.000.000 ненулевых элементов (например единичная матрица или такая, у которой в каждой строке/столбце по одному ненулевому элементу) легко поместится в памяти и займет приблизительно: `объем памяти необходимый для данного типа (np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64, np.float64, etc.)` плюс небольшие накладные расходы (информация о позиции ненулевых элементов в разреженной матрице). Если преобразовать такую матрицу в обычную или найти обратную ей то в результате надо будет хранить в памяти уже `1.000.000 x 1.000.000 = 1.000.000.000.000` (один триллион элементов, или около 3.6 TiB для 32-битных элементов)

Comment: `a^(-1)*c` выглядит как не лучший способ найти `b` из `a*b=c`. Лучше в сторону  `linalg.solve()` и аналогов посмотреть (не смотря на то что автор говорит). https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

Comment: @jfs, да, хорошая статья - спасибо! Сейчас добавлю в ответ...

Comment: можно явно причины указать: **1-** найти решение `A@x=b` быстрее чем `A⁻¹@c` **2-** даже если для разных `b` решение нужно найти (в этом случае факторизацию A матрицы можно сохранить, вместо A⁻¹) **3-** даже если уже известна `A⁻¹`, вычислительно более точный (accurate) результат  решение `A@x=b` даёт, вместо `A⁻¹@c` ([пример скалярного произведения неточный результат возвращающего](https://youtu.be/N05yYbUZMSQ?t=12m20s)) **4-** если  разреженная матрица A, c миллионом строк, то `A@x=b` можно быстро вычислить, но `A⁻¹` может занимать терабайты памяти.

Answer (score 4):

Произведением матриц очевидно во вашем случае *не разумеется* код

```
a * b
```

что в `numpy` значит просто *произведение элементов на согласных позициях*,

но *математическое произведение* (скалярное произведение *строк* матрицы `a` со *столбцами* матрицы `b`, что в `numpy` записывают как

```
np.dot(a, b)
```

или - более просто -

```
a.dot(b)
```

(что нужно использовать для проверки результата).

Подобно этому, простое деление

```
c / a
```

делением *элемент по элементу* (с автоматическим расширением матрицы `c` на `2 x 2`) на согласных позициях - и это опять *нет тем, что вам требуется*).

---

Из-за того решение вашего задания маленько сложнее:

Tак как `a * b = c` влечет за собой (после произведения обух страниц уравнения слева на `а`<sup>-1</sup>) `b = а`<sup>-1</sup> `* c`. Это в `numpy` записывают как

```
np.dot(np.linalg.inv(a), c)
```

или - более просто -

```
np.linalg.inv(a).dot(c)
```

что результат вашего задания.

Comment: да, я забыл указать, что `np.linalg.inv(a) * c` - будет неправильно работать для `NDArray`